# im new to programming. Im getting an error

Tags: python-3.x, attributeerror

```
class EceA:
    def __init__(s,name,age):
        s.name = name
        s.age = age
    def disp():
        return("the student name is" + s.name +"and the age is"+str(s.age))

reg1=("sam",21)


Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#27>", line 1, in <module>
    reg1.disp
AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'disp'
```

Comment: You are missing your class name, e.g. `reg1 = EceA('sam', 21)` and you are missing the `instance` variable for `disp()`. Note it is traditional to call the `instance` variable `self` (you used `s` in `__init__()`. These are elementary mistakes, I would read more beginners instructional material.

Answer (score 1):

You need to make an object of class with the parameters:

```
reg1 = EceA("sam",21)
reg1.disp()
```

Also you need to pass `self` paramter to the `disp()` function like:

```
def disp(self):
        return("the student name is" + self.name +"and the age is"+str(self.age))
```

Also in `init` you should pass '`self`' instead of '`s`' as the first paramter

Please read up https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html

Comment: Parens are unnecessary for `return` statements and using `str.format()` is probably a better approach: `return "the student name is {0.name} and the age is {0.age}".format(self)`

Comment: thank you sir. got the answer thank you very much for helping me.